# Prime number determination function gives wrong results

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I'm using Python to create a function that determines whether a number is prime or not. I believe I've done this right, but it fails on a few test cases. For example, for 10, it claims it is prime when it is not. Any suggestions?

```
def prime(number):
    result = None

    for i in range(2, number):
        if (number % i == 0):
            result = False

    result = True

    return result
```

Comment: please properly indent your function. This would always return True if you assign result to be True before return

Comment: check the control flow structure under [4.4](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your code:

> ```
> result = True
>
> return result
> ```

you set `result` to `True` and immediately return it. So nothing that came before that has any effect, at least not as far as the return value. That's why your function will return `True` for every number.

You should at least move or remove the `result = True` line, but I leave it to you to see what happens when you do.